# Wordpress : Get posts but not the full WP_Post object

Tags: wordpress, performance

Does anyone know if there is a way in Wordpress's core functions to retrieve posts but not the full `WP_Post` object ? For example let's say only the post title and permalink ?

The full post object is very big and the standard queries quickly become slow as your site grows.

There is a return argument in the standard `WP_Query` :
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#return-fields-parameter
But this only provides few options and you can't really retrieve what you want.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most appropriate solution I found to avoid big requests is to use the [WPGraphQL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-graphql/) plugin.
It allows you to make GraphQL API calls on your Wordpress database, and directly specify in your request what you want in return. The server appears to be way less overloaded.

In my case it is very appropriate, but if you want to stay in a classic PHP wordpress approach, the `get_results()` function is working too as said in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **get_results()** function. You can use simple SQL statements like SELECT x,y,z,... to get only the columns you need from a table of your choice.

Simple example:

```
function get_players() {
global $wpdb;
return $wpdb->get_results("SELECT a.id, a_name ROM player a");
```

}

Comment: This is what I thought. But still surprising from Wordpress, when you see the amount of available argument for the `WP_Query` class, that there is no one to do this.

Comment: You are right but don't forget that you are also able to use JOINs with the get_results() function. It would be difficult to develop a function which can also do this with simple parameters...

Answer (score 0):

The docs say that only 3 options are supported, and none of them allow an ad-hoc selection of fields. To do something more custom, you'd probably need to use the [wpdb class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/)